# Select row based on a rank and previously selected row

Tags: mysql, ranking

I am attempting to do a forum rank system, which can get one record at a time based on the previous record.

The example table is:

```
| POST_ID | POST_REPLIES |
--------------------------
|   1     |        5     | 
|   2     |        2     | 
|   3     |        8     |
|   4     |        8     |
|   5     |        12    |
--------------------------
```

If I do a simple query `ORDER BY POST_REPLIES DESC`, I get `POST_ID 5, 4, 3, 1, 2`.

But what I want to do is get onlythe next row (so a single row at a time), and based on the post it is currently at.

For example: if I am currently viewing post #3, there would be a button labeled 'next post with most replies' which would point to post # 4. 
I am currently having trouble dealing with duplicates, as I run into a loop between 3 and 4 (3 points to 4, and 4 points to 3 rather than 5)

I had played around with joining the table onto itself and comparing the rows to see which one was greater or less, but since I am using a limit of 1, the row is always 1 and thus useless. So the basic query I had was:

```
SELECT * FROM posts
   WHERE post_id != '$currentPost' 
   ORDER BY POST_REPLIES DESC, POST_ID DESC LIMIT 1
```

How can I do this?

Comment: are u intending to get a single reply instead of group ?

Comment: Correct, I am attempting to get the very next 'popular' post after the one being currently viewed.

Comment: For all those who want to know, I ended up creating a separate ranked table which got updated by cron every 4 hours, and used the generated rank # as a means to go to the previous to next picture.  The single query I had previously involved way too many subquerys, possbily due to my short experience with SQL.  The query I had was a mixture of mattedgod and newtovers solution, but took about 2-3 seconds to execute which was unacceptable.

Answer (score 1):

The first step you would need would be to "rank" the results. The best way I have found to do this in MySQL is with a variable like so:

```
SELECT posts.post_id, posts.post_replies, @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank
FROM posts, (SELECT @rank := 0) r
```

Then you would probably have to nest that query in another one to accomplish what you need. Let me know if that points you in the right direction

Comment: The only thing I wanted to avoid was ranking the whole table for each forum view, but I am experimenting doing a rank on a limited number of  posts that are directly above (in terms of # of replies) of the currently selected one.  i.e.  If I am viewing a post which has 10 replies, I will look at all posts that have three replies or more, and then rank those avoiding the post currently selected. I will keep you posted!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p.*
FROM (
  SELECT POST_ID, POST_REPLIES
  FROM posts
  WHERE POST_ID = @currentId) as cur
JOIN posts p 
  ON p.POST_REPLIES >= cur.POST_REPLIES
  AND p.POST_ID > cur.POST_ID
ORDER BY p.POST_REPLIES DESC, p.POST_ID
LIMIT 1 ;
```

Comment: This is similar to what I had attempted before;  The only problem with this is that it also sorts it by the ID, but a post with ID of 2 may be more popular (more replies) than a post with ID 30; in this case, If I was viewing post w/ ID 3, and it had 10 replies, and I clicked 'next', it would only go to posts that have a higher ID than the currentID.  I may try mixing this mattedgod's solution to see if I can come up with anything, I will keep you posted!

Answer (score 0):

Limit using a range, for example

```
 limit 0,1
```

where zero is the starting record and one is the number of records to fetch.

```
 limit 5,1
```

would get you the sixth record and so on. You can track the page number via post, get, or session and use it to manipulate the query in this way.

It is also common to fetch and store all the records, then present them per page, however this can be problematic if you expect to generate a large number of records.

Comment: That would work, but the system I am using requested by a form submission, and I can't use GET parameters on this project as the url has to be 'clean' and unmasked.